# Parallelisation in nested loops with OPENMP

Tags: c, loops, parallel-processing, dependencies, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize to this function in C using openmp but nothing seems to work out , I'm aware there are dependencies in the iterations and the two lines also but I'm stuck, can someone help me if possible.

```
void loop_reference(double C[N][N], double A[N][N], double B[N][N]) {
  size_t i, j;

  for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < N; j++) {
      B[i][j] = B[i-1][j] + A[i][j-1];
      A[i][j] = A[i-1][j] + C[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried separating the two lines and parallelize each loop but it doesn't work.

```
void loop_parallel(double C[N][N], double A[N][N], double B[N][N]) {
  size_t i, j;

  #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j) shared(A, B, C)
  for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < N; j++) {
      A[i][j] = A[i-1][j] + C[i][j];
      
    }
  }

  #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j) shared(A, B, C)
  for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < N; j++) {
      A[i][j] = A[i-1][j] + C[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Start by declaring your loop variables in the loop header. That will probably solve your problem. You can also declare `j` to be private, but using local variables is probably a simpler idea.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but it still gives me bad results unfortunately.

Comment: You might be able to parallelize this using wavefront parallelism and loop skewing.

Comment: *"I'm stuck"* or *"it doesn't work"* are not informative at all. Pleasetell  precisely what is the problem with your attempts: compilation error? Wrong results? Not the expected speed-up? Other?

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information , exactly i get wrong results even tho the speed-up is still higher than 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your algorithm can not be directly parallelized. Make a picture of the flow of data. Your `a[0,0]` is used by `a[0,1]` and `a[1,0]` so neither the outer nor the inner loop has independent iterations.

You need to rewrite this completely by iterating over "diagonals" in `i,j` space. First compute `a[0,0]`, then `a[1,0], a[0,1]`, then `a[2,0], a[1,1], a[0,2]`. In other words:

```
for (int d=0... 2N)
  for ( i,j such that i+j=s )
    compute a[i,j]
```

That gives you a sequential outer, and parallel inner loop. Full parallelism is not possible.

Of course, if this is a smoothing step in some iterative process you are actually not interested in complete reproducibility of the sequential result. In that case blithely declaring the whole loop nest parallel will correspond to "chaotic iteration" and the outer process may still converge. A little less drastic, if this is indeed a smoother, replace your lexicographic ordering by a red-black one, and you get a lot more parallelism. Again, without exactly reproducing the result of one sequential smoothing step in your original code.

Comment: Worth mentioning that only the inner loop can be parallelized, here.